# Hidden state/province field magento billing page

Tags: magento, field, billing, onepage-checkout

In billing page state/province page is not showing.There is a "Uncaught TypeError: $j(...).foundation is not a function" error in console.I think its a javascript conflict error.please help me.Dont know how to fix it.I am new to magento.

befor loading complete
[image]

The dropdown is there after loading but hidden.It shows when loading..

This page working fine but not showing any dropdown in state field

after loading

[image]

But Working fine on mobile devices

http://qwertykart.com/checkout/onepage/index/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see only one state there.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you're loading jquery twice:
[image]

Remove the one **after** the noconflict.js and you are good to go.